# Is this YACC specification to recognise infix expression correct?

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc

modified once more.  After removing the recursions, and writing a code for infix expression :
it also contains precedence checking, and no recursive grammar and no start Non terminal and also an error message.

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}

%token ALPHA NUMBER PLUS MINUS MUL DIV LPAR RPAR

%%

expr : expr PLUS term     { printf("its an infix expression");  }
     | expr MINUS term    
     | term 
     ; 

term : term MUL factor
     | term DIV factor
     | factor
     ;


factor : LPAR expr RPAR 
       | NUMBER 
       | ALPHA
       ;
%%
main()
{
yyparse();
}

int yyerror (char *s)
{

    printf("Not an infix expression");
}
```

is this okay now ?

Comment: `start -> expr -> start` is a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't. Apart from all the conflicts, it doesn't define any operator precedence. There are plenty of correct examples of LR expression grammars available on the Internet.

*EDIT:* Unary minus goes in the missing `primary` rule. From `factor` it usually goes like this:

```
factor: primary
    | primary '^' factor // exponentiation, note right-recursion for right-associativitity, or use %prec
    ;

primary: '(' expr ')'
    | '-' primary // unary minus; note recursion, to allow any number of them
    | NUMBER
    | IDENTIFIER
    ;
```

Comment: why should I add operator precedence ? I only need to check if it is an infix expression and not evaluate the expression.

Comment: @Anubha If you don't want to support operator precedence, you don't, OK. But that's not the only problem. Your basic problem is that your productions are both left-recursive and right-recursive. A look at some LR examples will show you how to do it. But beware, they will exhibit operator precedence as well :-|

Comment: Pretty close now. No unary minus? The name 'start' isn't good: this is actually the 'goal symbol', not a start state: the code block is only executed after 'expr' has been fully parsed, so it should be called something like 'program' or 'infix', or maybe even get rid of it and just have 'expr' as the goal symbol. You need to write something useful if you're going to override yyerror(), otherwise you may as well not override it at all. You certainly don't want to just suppress parsing errors like that.

Comment: Well thank you very much for your support. I tried unary minus as  MINUS expr but it gave rise to shift reduce conflict. I think the code is passable now..